# MAMP finds the MySql but my web page doesn't

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

My web page returns an error for the calls to mysql_connect() for this Mac OSX 10.6.6, MAMP setup.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 51 

Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 51 Could not connect to database, check database credentials in config.php`
```

When I echo the host, username, password for mysql_connect() they are the same as the MAMP preferences `'localhost:8889', 'root', 'password'`

Why can't mysql_connect access the database?

Comment: It seems like you are using the wrong mysql. Are there multiple mysql-installations on your computer? The correct sock should probably be /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: This has nothing to do with the username/password - your MAMP install has the wrong location for the mysql socket file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the current php.ini file (run a script containing:  and search for the location) and change the sock to the mamp-sock:

```
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If there are more occurrences of var/mysql/mysql.sock, change them as well.

Comment: The php.ini file for php 5.3.6 under the /Applications/MAMP directory has the right info for mysql.default_socket.  Could there be other reasons why mysql_connect() is looking at a different location?

Comment: I found that my setup was pointing to the standard apache configuration instead of the MAMP configuration.  In other words, the php specified in the apache httpd.conf was being used instead of the one specified in MAMP.  How do I make MAMP the default apache configuration?

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct Apache that is running, and that you are accessing it correctly? MAMP is on default running on port 8888, not port 80, and mysql is running on port 8889. Try to access via http://127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: I finally was able to revert to the standard apache webserver.  I edited the php.ini to point to the right mysql.sock.  After rebooting the PC the web page opened.  Thanks.